# What is the correct represention of (a (b . c) d) in box notation?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am doing the exercises in Paul Graham's *ANSI Common Lisp*. And I have had a key to the exercises by other person, which is:

http://www.shido.info/lisp/pacl2_e.html

After having finished the exercises for *Chapter 3*, I refer to that key to check my answers one by one. When it gets to the represention of `(a (b . c) d)`, I find that I cannot understand Shido's answer, which is:

http://www.shido.info/lisp/acl3-1d75.png

What exactly puzzled me is that in his answer `d` is not followed by `nil`.

So is his answer right? What is the correct represention of `(a (b . c) d)` indeed?

Comment: Shido's answer represents `(a (b . c) . d)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [sdraw program](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/Lisp/sdraw/sdraw.generic):

```
(load "sdraw.generic.lisp")

(sdraw '(a (b . c) d))

[*|*]--->[*|*]------->[*|*]--->NIL
 |        |            |
 v        v            v
 A       [*|*]--->C    D
          |
          v
          B
```

From this you can see that your idea is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The way to answer questions like this is to get the system to answer them for you.  Unfortunately doing this properly requires understanding of how the CL printing system works which is not that simple (in fact: I have forgotten how to do this properly!).  But you can write a mindless function which turns things into strings and which uses the object system to turn various sorts of things into strings in a way which is suitable.  This *isn't* going to work for objects which are not conses but which contain conses, but it is quite adequate for simple purposes:

```
(defgeneric thing->string (thing)
  (:method ((thing t))
   ;; any kind of thing we don't know about gets printed like this
   (format nil "~A" thing))
  (:method ((thing cons))
   ;; conses get printed like this
   (format nil "(~A . ~A)" 
           (thing->string (car thing))
           (thing->string (cdr thing)))))
```

Now: `(thing->string ...)` will answer your question.